# How to allow clicking on a pixbuf (image) in a treeview?

Tags: gtk, pygtk, clickable, gtk2

I want to make my `gtk.CellRendererPixbuf` in the treeview clickable so that I can call a function when user clicks on it. Is this possible and how can this be done?

I'm working with PyGTK, but answers in C or PHP or anything else would be acceptable. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The C documentation of [GtkCellRenderer](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkCellRenderer.html#GtkCellRenderer.description) states that:

> Beyond merely rendering a cell, cell renderers can optionally provide active user interface elements. A cell renderer can be activatable like GtkCellRendererToggle, which toggles when it gets activated by a mouse click, or it can be editable like GtkCellRendererText, which allows the user to edit the text using a GtkEntry. To make a cell renderer activatable or editable, you have to implement the activate or start_editing virtual functions, respectively.

What is unfortunate is that this information is missing from the [pyGTK documentation](http://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtkcellrenderer.html), but the information is available in the [`activate`](http://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtkcellrenderer.html#method-gtkcellrenderer--activate) signal documentation.

Comment: Tried it earlier but faced some problem. I will try it later and accept this as an answer when it works. Thanks again.

Comment: I am struggling to use `activate()`. Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Just give a look to GTK source code for examples. Here's how the activate signal is implemented for GtkCellRendererToggle: http://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/gtk/gtkcellrenderertoggle.c?id=2.24.14#n393

Comment: TypeError: <Gtk.CellRendererPixbuf object at 0x7fd3f34d35a0 (GtkCellRendererPixbuf at 0x262bd10)>: unknown signal name: activate